# SSL handshake failed : self signed certificate in certificate chain in kafka broker SSL

Tags: security, ssl, apache-kafka, openssl, keytool

I get this error on broker when I try to setup SSL in my localhost kafka:

> [2023-07-24 23:41:36,219] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed authentication with /127.0.0.1 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)

trying to see exactly which problem I have:

```
openssl s_client -debug -connect localhost:9093 -tls1_2 -showcerts
```

Result:

```
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 9FF501EBB724972D231A2A606398F69A710FDC419D706142E3DE73B7EB1C79B1
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: AAA6240C9BA554D6F0D442A5CD4F3E697656F96D40D087A9779CBDD5EDA1246C7CE4BA450DE9842E50AF588FF49D5990
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1690234896
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
    Extended master secret: yes
```

I using WSL on windows with Ubuntu 20.04, using tls version below 1.2 making different error inherent to my ubuntu version.

I generated my truststore, ca and keystore different way but they alway lead to the same problem, so I guess the problem come from me and not the script/tutorial.

let say I used the confluent script: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-platform-security-tools/blob/master/kafka-generate-ssl.sh

my broker configuration:

```
ssl.keystore.location=/mnt/e/.../keystore/kafka.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=password
ssl.key.password=password
ssl.truststore.location=/mnt/e/.../truststore/kafka.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
ssl.ca.location=/mnt/e/.../ca-key
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
ssl.client.auth=required
```

I set my CN to `localhost` in every certificate

```
subject=C = Unknown, ST = Unknown, L = Unknown, O = Unknown, OU = Unknown, CN = localhost
```

Now the CA will be imported into the keystore.

```
You will be prompted for the keystore's password and a confirmation that you want to
import the certificate.
Owner: CN=localhost, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, ST=Some-State, C=AU
Issuer: CN=localhost, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, ST=Some-State, C=AU
```

I am little bit lost about what to try next.
using Apache kafka 2.5

Comment: What part of 'self-signed certificate in certificate chain' don't you understand? You can only use *any* certificate if the signer is trusted by the peer. In the case of self-signed certificates it is up to you to ensure that. Off topic.

Comment: the whole part. if the certificate is signed by my ca, it's self signed, but how can i bypass this ?

Answer (score 1):

When you sign your certificate, include a Subject Alternative Name (SAN) record:

```bash
echo "subjectAltName = IP:127.0.0.1" > v3.ext
openssl x509 -req -CA ca-cert -CAkey ca-key -in your_cert_sig_req_file -out cert-signed -days 3650 -CAcreateserial -extfile v3.ext
```